# D3 Scale SVG children

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am using topojson with D3 to create a map. On the map im doing the following to plot locations. However when you zoom into the map i want the .place circle's to get smaller on zoom.

**Objects**

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("id", "map");

var g = svg.append("g")
    .call(zoom);

var map = g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,0) scale(1)");
```

**Scaling**

```
s = 4000;

zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .translate(projection.translate())
    .scale(projection.scale())
    .scaleExtent([s, s * 4])
    .on("zoom", zoommove);
```

**Plotting the places:**

```
topGroup = map.append('g').attr('id', 'mapGroup');

topGroup.selectAll(".place")
    .data(topojson.feature(mapData, transformedPlotData).features)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return path.centroid(d)[0] })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return path.centroid(d)[1] })
    .attr("r", 4);
```

**Zoom**

```
function zoommove() {

    var t1 = projection.translate(),
        t2 = d3.event.translate,
        t = [t2[0]-t1[0], t2[1]-t1[1]];

    map.attr("transform",
        "translate("+t+") " +
        "scale("+(d3.event.scale/s)+")"
    );

}
```

Thanks all

Comment: Can you post a working example on JSFiddle or some other similar repository? What do you mean about making the circle smaller? Do you mean keeping it in a constant size while zooming in? Is the zooming algorithm above actually working the way you expect it to? What's happening exactly? Please take some time to describe your problem in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your zoom function, set the size of the circles according to the zoom scale:

```
.attr("r", 4/zoom.scale());
```

Something like this:

```
function zoommove() {

 var t1 = projection.translate(),
    t2 = d3.event.translate,
    t = [t2[0]-t1[0], t2[1]-t1[1]];

 map.attr("transform",
    "translate("+t+") " +
    "scale("+(d3.event.scale/s)+")"
  );

topGroup.selectAll("circle")
    .attr("r", 4/zoom.scale());

}
```